# Are there any (automated) solutions for filling out application forms?

Tags: application

How do people usually handle so many application forms when applying? I find I need to fill out similar information for every single program I'm applying to, and each takes me almost one hour. Does anyone have a better solution?

(I'm applying for postgraduate)

Comment: You may be applying to too many programs.

Comment: An hour per application filling out a form doesn't sound onerous to me. You will need to spend more than that much time tailoring your statement of purpose and cover letter for each institution. @BryanKrause may have the right answer.

Comment: thanks! I'm also spending the most time on the state of purpose and cover letters, and actually, that's why I'm wondering if there's any better way to fill that repetitive information...

Answer (score 4):

Personally I wouldn't fully trust any automated system, as each application system seems to have its own idiosyncrasies. Built-in auto-fill functionality in web browsers is helpful for names and addresses, but does mess up every now and then, and those fields are a lot more standardized than the ways to list your degrees and experience. For job and visa applications I instead find it helpful to have a text document with full versions of all the standard responses. Keep it open in a window next to the application form and copy/paste information as needed, massaging the way it's expressed when appropriate. This tends to speed up filling out the mind-numbing parts of applications (mostly because you won't waste time repeatedly looking things up) and helps avoid mistakes, leaving more time for tailoring application documents.